# How to apply matrices - an understanding request

Tags: c, matrix

Suppose I have a cube as

```
P1(0, 0, 0) P5(0, 0, 1)
P2(1, 0, 0) P6(1, 0, 1)
P3(0, 1, 0) P7(0, 1, 1)
P4(1, 1, 0) P8(1, 1, 1)
```

Now I need to apply transformation/rotation/scale matrices. Say,

```
transform = Pt(3, 3, 5)
rotation = 30º
scale = 2x`
```

Ok. But, where do I put each of these values into the matrices in order to get the final result? That confuses me alot.

**edit**

Lets say, for the P2, I have:

```
| 1 |   | a b c |
| 0 | x | d e f | = R
| 0 |   | g h i |
```

But what do I have in `a,b,c,d,...i` ?

Comment: Can you explain how you think you would do it?

Comment: @Jason - tell me if my edit enlighten

Comment: I think I showed you for the special case of rotation about the x-axis.  Must I spoon feed you for y- and z- as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it with a single operation you need a 4x4 matrix. Look at http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~ie_246/Lecture/OpenGLMatrices.ppt for some details and examples.

In the end you chain the transformations like this

```
point[i] = T1*T2*T3*..*vertex[i]
```

[image: PDF Conversion]

Comment: You can use the Google docs viewer to see it: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~ie_246/Lecture/OpenGLMatrices.ppt

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the 8 points on the corners of the cube are a 3x1 vector.  Your matrix transformations are 3x3 matricies.

Rotation about what axis?  That will change what that rotation matrix will look like.  Here's what it is about the x-axis:

```
     | +cos(theta) -sin(theta)  0 | 
Rx = | +sin(theta) +cos(theta)  0 |
     | 0           0            1 |
```

The scale is easy: Multiply all the x-coordinates by a factor of two.

```
    | 2  0  0 |
S = | 0  1  0 |
    | 0  0  1 |
```

Apply these to each of your points.

Comment: Rx looks like an x rotation in 2d with homogenized coordinates (x,y,W). Or its a z-rotation in 3d with non-homogenized coordinates.

Comment: It's a CW rotation through an angle about the x-axis, as stated.  It's an example to show how to think about one rotation.

Comment: Look at the "Rotations" slide and see that it's the same as the third example.

Comment: Yeah, it is the third example which is a z rotation. Here's another [source](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/rotationMatrices.html) from n OpenGL tutorial.